# x86 - Gas/AT&T/Linux trouble with stosb lodsb

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, att

I posted a question a while back about this but I figured I would start a new thread as the code has changed entirely.  I am trying to store a byte string into a memory address created by malloc.  When executing the program from terminal I get:

```
Loaded into eax: 49
```

I have been following the Intel [manual(pdf)](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.pdf) exactly as said (or atleast I think).  Page 175 for General Purpose Register String Instructions.

```
    .global main
.text
str: .string "Loaded into eax: %d\n"
one: .string "1"

main:
pushl   $4          #push size of malloc
call    malloc      #call malloc
popl    %ecx        #clear malloc size off of stack
movl    %eax, %edi  #move address to destination
movl    %edi, %ecx  #
movb    one, %al    #move a 1 into %al
stosb               #store the 1 in %al to the address in destination
movl    %ecx, %esi  #move address to source for lodsb
movl    $0, %eax     #clear eax register
lodsb               #load content of (%esi) into %eax
pushl   %eax        #push that content onto stack
pushl   $str        #push string format onto stack
call    printf      #call printf
popl    %ecx        #clear stack
popl    %ecx        #clear stack
end:
```

Comment: Off the top of my head, doesn't `stosb` change the value of `edi`?

Comment: @Zack is right. you're storing to the first byte of the malloc'ed buffer, then loading from the second byte.

Comment: Im not sure I understand what you guys mean.  Aren't I storing a one? in the address of edi?  Where am I only storing the first byte and I can't seem to find anywhere in manual that says stosb changes value of edi?

Comment: `stosb` increments `edi`, which you then place in `esi` and use for reading from memory. So you're reading from the byte _after_ where you placed the '1'.

Comment: Okay.  Kind of pisses me off this isn't covered in the manual but anyhow, I brought the malloced address to a secondary location and then placed it in %esi...when I run the program I am now getting '49' as a return...any thoughts?

Comment: In the pdf you linked to, last paragraph of page 1453 (if you go by the actual page count. The page number on the bottom of the page is a useless "Vol 2B 4-381"). The stuff you're reading in Vol 1 Chapter 7 (your page 175) is not nearly verbose enough to be a thorough explanation of anything.

Comment: Ok thank you.  I have updated my code (above) to show what is changed.  Any idea why I am getting a 49?

Comment: I am getting 49 because one is 49 in ascii